# jQuery drag and drop colour div to change background of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have the following `HTML`, containing 4 `<div>`'s - 2 are doors and 2 are colors, as you can guess from their `id`.

I'd like to be able to drag either colour to either door (such as blue on the left door and black on the right) and change the background colour on the style.

```
<div id="door1" style="background: #fff;"></div>
<div id="door2" style="background: #fff;"></div>
<div id="black"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
```

I'd be grateful even if someone could point me in the right direction at least.

Comment: .draggable is the way to achieve this, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4):

You should initialize your color `<div>`'s as [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and door `<div>`'s as [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) widgets using `.draggable()` and `.droppable()` methods respectively.

Then you can use the [`drop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) event handler of `droppable` for changing the background color. Inside the handler, you can access the droppable using `this` and dragged element using `ui.draggable` as shown below:

```js
$(".color").draggable({
  revert:true
});
$(".door").droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    console.log(ui.draggable)
    $(this).css("background-color", ui.draggable.attr("id"));
  }
});
```

```css
.door {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
}
.color {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.white {
  background: #fff;
}
#black {
  background: #000;
}
#blue {
  clear: left;
  background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="door1" class="door white"></div>
<div id="door2" class="door white"></div>
<div id="black" class="color"></div>
<div id="blue" class="color"></div>
```

---

Side note: I've removed the inline css and is using css classes, So that you can avoid duplication of styles and keep your HTML clean. You can read more about [Why Use CSS @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Answer (score 0):

On the stop event of "draggable" check which div was the target (getting 'left' and 'top' attributes of the div that was dragged) and paint it with the color from the div that was dragged.