# jQuery drag and drop div to change image in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I need to do a drag and drop function from a div to another with some images inside.
The issue is that i wont show a different img for every different element that i drag.

For example:
I need that dragging #element1 in images's div i show the img with .element1 class and i hide img with .element2 class.

```
<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element2"></div>

<div id="images">
<img class="element1" src="1.jpg" />
<img class="element2" src="2.jpg" />
</div>
```

It's possible?
I see this method [jQuery drag and drop colour div to change background of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555606/jquery-drag-and-drop-colour-div-to-change-background-of-another) but is with background image.

I tired here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wolfovs/ab0566Lt/1/

Someone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include jquery and jquery-ui library in your html head or before close body tag

```
$("#images").droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    if((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'element1'){
       $('.element2').hide();
       $('.element1').show();
    }else if((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'element2'){
       $('.element1').hide();
       $('.element2').show();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/GRDww/67/)

Comment: Hi, are you sure? i tried but doesn't works. Can you do a JF?

Comment: look we are here not to create a JF We're here to modify yours to solve your issue .. So you can create a JF with your code and I'll check it for you..

Comment: Yes you have reason! And thanks for your help.
It's here! 
http://jsfiddle.net/wolfovs/ab0566Lt/1/

Comment: So nice! Thanks so much! Only a thing, there is a way to show only a img at the start? Maybe is enough a display none on a img?

Comment: use display:none in your css to the class you want to hide it